# How to enable DPRP in Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I just created a Business account. (It gives the status as Unverified because i haven't entered my credit card information). I want to do Direct Recurring payments. (Accept credit card details from user from my site).

I got an error which states `DPRP is disabled for this merchant.`. This is because i haven't enabled DPRP (DirectPayment Recurring Payments).

I have attached a screenshot below, where i have tried to enable it. But it just gives me a Note, but doesn't enable it. How can i correct this error? help

Note: This is not the live version of the website, i am just testing it currently.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a problem in the Sandbox enabling DPRP. I would contact [MTS](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/) and see if they can enable it for you. Note that you don't need DPRP to simply accept credit cards, only to make recurring payments.

Answer (score 9):

You need to enable the "Pro" mode for your merchant sandbox account in order to accept recurring payment by credit card

Go to "**Sandbox accounts**" and click on the account marked as "**Business**" in column "Type". You will see 2 new links "Profile" and "Notifications".

Click on "**Profile**" and navigate into different tabs. You will find a button for active "**Pro**" features on this business sandbox account.

Hope my english is understandable.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Your English is excellent, you only missed one plural form. Cheers

Comment: Thank you Jim. I'm glad to see it still help one year later.

Comment: I'm active business-pro account but still getting this error can any help me

Comment: hi i can not able to find the above mention way, can you please explain briefly.

Comment: I am getting DPRP is disabled for this merchant even after converting to pro.

Comment: As per your instructions, We have already a Business Pro account. How could I enable DPRP(Direct Payment Recurring Payment)?